# how to read child resultset from REST Json using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented $expand REST service(SAP NW Gateway) which is working fine..here I am performing $exapnd of odata, and I developing my front-end using Angular.

I am struggling to read the child result-set of payload, below is my sample payload

```
{
d: 
{
results: 
[1]
0:  
{
__metadata: 
{
id: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/HeaderDetails('4500077411')"
uri: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/HeaderDetails('4500077411')"
type: "MYEXPAND.Header"
}
-
CCode: "1042"
PONumber: "4500077411"
DocType: "UB"
NavItem: 
{
results: 
[2]
0:  
{
__metadata: 
{
id: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00010')"
uri: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00010')"
type: "MYEXPAND.Item"
}
-
PoNumber: "4500077411"
PoItem: "00010"
Material: "A10001"
}
-
1:  
{
__metadata: 
{
id: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00020')"
uri: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00020')"
type: "MYEXPAND.Item"
}
-
PoNumber: "4500077411"
PoItem: "00020"
Material: "E-M-SAMS-Q001-0009"
}
-
-
}
-
}
-
-
}
-
}
```

in my controller I can read like $scope.resultsset= data.d.dresults, but here in Expand I need to read my child data from navitem-results for the respective PONumber results.

here is with indentation

```
{
    d: 
    {
        results: 
        [1]
        0:  
        {
            __metadata: 
            {
                id: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/HeaderDetails('4500077411')"
                uri: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/HeaderDetails('4500077411')"
                type: "MYEXPAND.Header"
            }
            -
            CCode: "1042"
            PONumber: "4500077411"
            DocType: "UB"
            NavItem: 
            {
                results: 
                [2]
                0:  
                {
                    __metadata: 
                    {
                        id: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00010')"
                        uri: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00010')"
                        type: "MYEXPAND.Item"
                    }
                    -
                    PoNumber: "4500077411"
                    PoItem: "00010"
                    Material: "A10001"
                }
                -
                1:  
                {
                    __metadata: 
                    {
                        id: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00020')"
                        uri: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/MYEXPAND/Items(PoNumber='4500077411',PoItem='00020')"
                        type: "MYEXPAND.Item"
                    }
                    -
                    PoNumber: "4500077411"
                    PoItem: "00020"
                    Material: "E-M-SAMS-Q001-0009"
                }
                -
                -
            }
            -
        }
        -
        -
    }
    -
}
```

help me to sort this, thanks
Rajesh

Comment: Ever heard of indentation?

Comment: Hi Biffen, thanks for the advise...as I am not a JavaScript developer and not aware about indentation  earlier...honestly :)

Comment: Then I suggest your first step is to get a decent editor that can help you with that.

Comment: I have reposted with sublime,please revisit my request

Comment: Isn't it simply  '4500077411' === data.d.results[0].NavItem.Results[0].PoNumber  or '4500077411' === data.d.results[0].PONumber  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved my self after searching few more things in google, below is the way I cracked it

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="Y in results">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat=" Z in Y.NavItem.results">
<b>PO Number </b>: {{Z.PoNumber}}
<b>PO Item </b>: {{Z.PoItem}}
<b>Material</b> : {{Z.Material}}
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the support
Rajesh